# What is the correct format for sending cookies in a post request with Python Requests?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'd like to set cookies to URL before parsing it with BS4. First of all, I'm not sure, if I'm using the correct format for cookies. Here is how they look like in chrome DevTool:

- *Name: aep_usuc_f*
- *Value: site=rus&c_tp=USD&region=IE&b_locale=ru_RU*

Here is my code:

```
url = 'https://example.com/item/123.html'
cookies = {'aep_usuc_f': 'site=rus&c_tp=USD&region=IE&b_locale=ru_RU'}

s = requests.Session()
s.post('https://example.com/item/123.html', cookies=cookies)
r = s.get('https://example.com/item/123.html')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
```

This doesn't seem to work. Cookies are not getting set. Appreciate your help.

Comment: You're first sending a POST request with cookies, and then sending a GET request with no cookies. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: I'm a newbie, so don't take my code too seriously. The default web page is in Russian and has currency of RUB. I want to change currency to USD and then  parse the page with BS4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you just want to retrieve and parse the contents of the web-page, there's no need for a POST request here (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get)). Just use:

```
s = requests.Session()
r = s.get('https://example.com/item/123.html', cookies=cookies)
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. But how do I pass this request with cookies to BS4? I'm getting the AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'.

Comment: That means that the request isn't returning anything. Are you sure the web-page URL is valid?

Comment: There was a mistake on my side. Everything works now. Thanks a lot for your help!